# Customize Actionbar's back button

Tags: android

[image]   [image]

```
<style name="MyActionBar.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_style</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

How can i customize the actibar's navigate up button. Actualy i want that it's colors changes when i click it. For example Whatsapp, when i click back button the button's background color happens blue.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to override the `android:homeAsUpIndicator` for your custom theme for your project.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
          <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_up_caret</item>
    </style>
```

Then set your custom there as the app theme in your manifest file (if you have not already):

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.app"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the image of the icon programmatically:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
//set icon
actionBar.setIcon(some Icon);
```

You could change this Icon on every click.

If you want to set a color as Icon:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.niceBackgroundColor)));
```

Comment: i dont want to change icon, i want icons background color

Comment: do you mean the background of the actionbar?

Comment: I want just a button's hover event, when i click back the back's background color change

Comment: If you use whatapps, please click homeUpIndicator button. When you click you will see that lt's background will be blue. How can i do it

Comment: I don't use WhatsApp. But if you want to change the background of the button. You need two images. E.g. one with a white background and one with a blue background. If you click the button, you change the image via setIcon().
Or you can take Andre Perkins solution and do it via xml.